# What is wrong with this SQL Query? (MySQL Error)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

What is wrong with my query here?

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin_nav1 WHERE Active = 'YES' AND WHERE LinkedID = '$WID' ORDER by 'OrderSet' ASC") or die(mysql_error());
```

I keep getting this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE LinkedID = '6' ORDER by 'OrderSet' ASC' at line 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have only one `WHERE` clause. `AND` operator is enough to separate the two conditions.

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    admin_nav1 
WHERE   Active = 'YES' AND LinkedID = '$WID'  // <<== one WHERE clause
ORDER   by OrderSet ASC
```

One more thing, your query will not `ORDER` the rows correctly because you have wrap the column name `OrderSet` with single quotes thus converting it into a string. When you are concern of the column names if they are a reserved keyword or not, you can either wrap it with a backtick or supply an alias on the table and use the column names with that alias to delimit the column but **not** with single quotes.

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use where once

```
SELECT * FROM admin_nav1 
WHERE Active = 'YES' AND  .....
```

and then use and operators for more conditions.